# Serilog LogContext pushed properties not logged using Owin Middleware

Tags: owin, serilog

This is my **Owin** LoggingMiddlware

```
    public class LoggerMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public LoggerMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
        {
        }

        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            string userName = "Anonymous";
            if (context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                userName = context.Authentication.User.Identity.Name;
            using (LogContext.Push(new PropertyEnricher("User", userName)))
            {
                Log.Debug("LogContext impostato");
                await Next.Invoke(context);
                Log.Debug("LogContext disposato");
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is my Log static setup in global.asax **Application_Start**.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .WriteTo.Async(a => a.RollingFile(pathFormat: "C:/temp/HcWeb/Log-HCWEB-{Date}.txt", 
                 outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Properties}{Message} 
                                 {NewLine}{Exception}"))
                 .CreateLogger();
```

For some reason that I don't understand, pushed properties are logged only in middleware but these are not presents in Controllers action methods.

This is my rolling file:

```
2020-06-02 17:52:49.052 +02:00 [Debug] { User: "D'ANDREA VITO" }LogContext impostato
2020-06-02 17:52:53.846 +02:00 [Debug] { ** NOTHING HERE ** }Hai aperto Stato Pratica
2020-06-02 17:53:13.660 +02:00 [Debug] { User: "D'ANDREA VITO" }LogContext disposato
```

In similar posts someone forgot the call Enrich.FromLogContext() but this is not my case.
Should I create Logger in another way, instead of global.asax?

Comment: How are you getting a hold of the Serilog `ILogger` in the controllers? How are your registering Serilog with the web host?

Comment: I just use the static class Log, as the docs says:
[link](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers)

Comment: What runtime are you using?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.1